# Set static text color Win32

Tags: c, api, winapi

I am making a dll that controls a dialogue box.  I like to get a certain area to have red text.  This code does compile, but the effect is not seen.  Here is the area where the dialogProc is done:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:     
        CheckDlgButton(hDlg, IDC_CHECK, FALSE);
        EnableWindow(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDOK), FALSE);
        return TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDC_CHECK:
            if (IsDlgButtonChecked(hDlg, IDC_CHECK))
            {
                EnableWindow(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDOK), TRUE);
                EnableWindow(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDCANCEL), FALSE);
            }
            else
            {
                EnableWindow(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDOK), FALSE);
                EnableWindow(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDCANCEL), TRUE);
            }
            break;
        case IDOK:
            {           
                EndDialog(hDlg, TRUE);
                return FALSE;
            }
        case IDCANCEL:
            {               
                EndDialog(hDlg, FALSE);
                return FALSE;
            }
        case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
            // Set the colour of the text for our URL
            if ((HWND)lParam == GetDlgItem(hDlg,IDC_WARNING)) 
            {
                // we're about to draw the static
                // set the text colour in (HDC)lParam
                SetBkMode((HDC)wParam,TRANSPARENT);
                SetTextColor((HDC)wParam, RGB(255,0,0));
                return (BOOL)CreateSolidBrush (GetSysColor(COLOR_MENU));
            }
    return TRUE;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: are you sure that your code block is executed?

Comment: The case statement is, but I think that is more based on user interaction, such as clicking buttons.

I am not too sure how to set color statically on Win32 API.  I am more used to C++ where there was a color attribute on the object.

Comment: Well, the blue is now working, I now have white background everywhere else!

Comment: All of the backgrounds are okay except for the icon control.  It is marked transparent too.  Not too sure why that control now has a white background!

Comment: Yeah, I realised that later, that's how I got it to work now, I moved it out of that block, I just put it in the wrong spot by accident!

But, I can't get my icon to have a transparent background now.  I moved the transparent portion outside of the if, so everything is transparent, since before the black text had a white background, but i couldn't get the icon now to have a transparent background.  IUt was prior to this working.

Comment: I think this will be solved better if I used a transparent PNG file, but how do I include the PNG?  I can import the PNG into the resource manager, but Picture control won't accept it in the rc editor.  How do I add it programatically?  Sorry for being so naive, I never done this sort of stuff before, so I am trying to learn!

Comment: There isn't native support in old-style controls for PNG files. But, if you have an icon created using the stock tools in visual studio, the transparent bits can be set using the monitor icon filled with the off-green color.

If you'd like me to take a deeper look, you can email me at the address in my profile.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC is a separate message from WM_COMMAND. Your desired handling of the message appears to be correct except that the check for the message is inside your check for WM_COMMAND specific items. Try reorganizing your outer switch statement. Perhaps something like the following:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hDlg, UINT message, 
                            WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:         
        // ...
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDC_CHECK:
            // ...
            break;
        case IDOK:
            // ...
            break;
        case IDCANCEL:
            // ...
            break;
        }
        break;
    case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
        // Set the colour of the text for our URL
        if ((HWND)lParam == GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_WARNING)) 
        {
                // we're about to draw the static
                // set the text colour in (HDC)lParam
                SetBkMode((HDC)wParam,TRANSPARENT);
                SetTextColor((HDC)wParam, RGB(255,0,0));
                // NOTE: per documentation as pointed out by selbie, GetSolidBrush would leak a GDI handle.
                return (BOOL)GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_MENU);
        }
        break;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Also note that it would be kinda weird to filter WM_COMMAND's wParam argument when wParam is supposed to provide the HDC for WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC.

[WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC Notification at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787524%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Is there a way to do this without handling the CTLCOLORSTATIC message >?

Comment: The above solution leaks at least one GDI object.  There's no code to call DeleteObject for the call to CreateSolidBrush.  I'm not sure if WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC gets passed on each paint operation or if it's only on the dialog initialization.  But a leak is a leak. The code above should create the brush in WM_INITDIALOG and then call DeleteObject in WM_DESTROY.  Alternatively, GetSysColorBrush may be a better solution for the above code instead of calling CreateSolidBrush.